# How do I authenticate a user in Laravel 8 Jetstream only if his status is active?

Tags: php, laravel, fortify, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am building a Laravel 8 application and have successfully implemented authentication. Now I want to check if a user's status is active before logging him in. I have added a field in the users table

```
username varchar
password varchar
....
status tinyint(1)
...
```

I am using *JetStream* and *Fortify*

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize user authentication from `app\Providers\JetStreamServiceProvider.php`, on `boot` method :

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

public function boot()
{
    $this->configurePermissions();

    Jetstream::createTeamsUsing(CreateTeam::class);
    Jetstream::updateTeamNamesUsing(UpdateTeamName::class);
    Jetstream::addTeamMembersUsing(AddTeamMember::class);
    Jetstream::deleteTeamsUsing(DeleteTeam::class);
    Jetstream::deleteUsersUsing(DeleteUser::class);
    // Below code is for your customization
    Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

       if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            if ($user->status == 1) {  // it will return if status == 1
                 return $user;
            }
       }

    });
}
```

See the official `Jetstream` documentation of **[Customizing User Authentication](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#customizing-user-authentication)**

Comment: Thanks for the example. It is not better to add another "where" to the query?

Comment: @JuliSmz,  yes you can

Comment: You do not check for password!!! Everyone who is active can login with a wrong password in your example!!!

Comment: Yes u can. Have you tried your snipped? i tried it right now and you can login with a random password

Comment: in the official example is a password check: $user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)

Comment: how can you send the different error messages to the user because it still shows "These credentials do not match our records."

Answer (score 1):

This is with a custom error message.

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        if ($user->active == 1) { 
            return $user;
        }
        throw ValidationException::withMessages(['Your Message Here!']);        
    }

});
```

Make sure your import the ValidationException

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

You can also just throw a customer 403 message

```
abort(403,'Your Message Here!')
```

Answer (score -2):

You should add too: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;