# How to redirect users conditionally?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am on Laravel with Jetstream, I am using responses to redirect a user, once after a user registers himself. I am successfully able to redirect users whenever a user registers. Only admins can create users or invite them. So whenever I create a user from the admin panel, it redirects me to the `route('frontend.dashboard')` which can only be viewed by the user with a client role. So as I am logged in as an administrator, it throws me a status error 404.

How can I omit the redirection part when an administrator is registering an account. So a user is only redirected whenever he himself registers.

- RegisterResponse.php

```
class RegisterResponse implements RegisterResponseContract
{

    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRoles(['Administrator', 'Employee'])) {
            return redirect()->route('backend.dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->route('frontend.dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: This may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835186/how-do-i-authenticate-a-user-in-laravel-8-jetstream-only-if-his-status-is-active/64835805?r=SearchResults#64835805)

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware to restrict user to redirect different routes.

Otherwise you can create two tables named "permissions" and "features" in your database.
Table columns should be like this:

**- Table(Permissions):**

```
 Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->id();
                    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
                    $table->unsignedInteger('feature_id');
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
```

**- Table(Features):**

```
Schema::create('features', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

Now make a helper function like this which will check if the particular user has access to redirect to the particular route.
**

- Helper function:

**

```
function has_permission($feature_name)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->role->name == 'admin' ){
        $status = True;
    }else{
        $feature = Feature::where('name', $feature_name)->first();
        $status = Permission::where([['user_id', $user->id],['feature_id', $feature->id]])->exists();
    }
    return $status;
}
```

So, now you can add condition in your Controllers every functions which redirect to a page like this:

```
if (!has_permission('shipments')) {
            $notification=array(
                'message' => 'Sorry ! You do not have permission',
                'alert-type' => 'warning'
            );
```

Thank you.Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the revert! I'll try implementing your solution.