# Laravel fortify, prevent user login if user not active

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with authentication users, in table users I have column `active`. I need prevent user authentication if `active = 0` and show on login page message: `Sorry. Your account is disabled.`. How I can do it? I tried use:

```
/**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
public function boot()
{
   // ...

Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if(!$user->active) {
        redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Your account is disabled!');
    }

    if ($user &&
        Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        return $user;
    }
  });
}
```

This working, but not working when user is being registered. After registration, he login without my verification on `active = 0`

I tried and middleware CheckActiveUser:

```
  /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!$request->user()->active) {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with(['status' => 'Your account is not activated!']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But I ger error `site.com redirected you too many times.`

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified', 'checkActiveUser']], function() {
Route::get('/anamnesis', 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AnamnesisController@index')->name('anamnesis');
Route::view('/console', 'console')->name('home');
Route::view('/history', 'history')->name('history');
Route::view('/calendar', 'calendar')->name('calendar');
Route::get('/results', 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\ResultsController@index')->name('results');
Route::delete('/results/{document}', 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\ResultsController@delete')->name('documents.delete');
Route::view('/conversations', 'conversations')->name('conversations');
Route::view('/order-payment', 'orderpayment')->name('order-payment');
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835805/4575350

Comment: @sta -_- I use it see above

Comment: I'm going to leave this link here so that if someone has a problem related to the automatic Fortify login after registration they don't have to go through the horrible experience that I just had:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397645/how-can-i-disable-auto-login-after-registration-in-laravel-8

Answer (score 1):

Fortify will automatically login an user if you return the user from the `CreateNewUser` class. Instead of returning the created user check, if the user is created successfully and throw an exception along with flash message. Fortify will try to redirect you to the home page and will return you back to the login page as user is not authenticated showing you the flash message. Below is a peek at the process in the file `App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser`.

```php
public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique(User::class),
            ],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'is_active' => false
        ]);

        if ($user && !$user->is_active) {
            event(new Registered($user));
            flash('Registration successful! Awaiting approval from admin.')->success()->important();
            throw new \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException\AuthenticationException();
        }

    }
```

I think there might be other solution to hook into any of the Fortify events to do that even more gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify automatically logs the `user` in once they have successfully registered, bypassing the authentication logic in your question.

**Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController**

```
public function store(Request $request,
                      CreatesNewUsers $creator): RegisterResponse
{
    event(new Registered($user = $creator->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard->login($user);

    return app(RegisterResponse::class);
}
```

To achieve the outcome you're looking for, I would create a [`middleware`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) that functions in a similar manner to the Fortify [`verified`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#protecting-routes) middleware.

[Define a `middleware`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware) that asserts that the `active` status of your `user` is truthy (1/true) and if so allow them to continue, otherwise redirect them to an error page informing them their account is not yet active.

Comment: middleware I tried, but doesn't work ( I get error that many redirects..

Comment: @RedFox Either you middleware logic is flawed, or you need to alter the order in which the middleware executes.

Comment: @RedFox The error suggests you're in a redirect loop. Have you applied your `middleware` to the `login` route by any chance? Can you provide your `routes` in your question?

Comment: Where is your `login` route defined?

Comment: Is not defined, this is fortify. Routes in vendor.

Comment: I tried add to Route::post('/login') middleware in vendor, doesn't work, $request()->user() is null...

Comment: Are you sure the user is being authenticated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try by flushing the session first:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->user()->status->status === 'inactive') {
        $request->session()->flush();
        return redirect()->route('login')->with(['status' => 'Your account is not activated!']);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```